# WPF KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation with custom control

Tags: wpf, keyboard-navigation

I need the TabNavigation to Traverse the entire VisualTree .

Iv'e get a custom control in a view which i need  it's inner elements to take part in the View's TabNavigation.

I need to use TabIndex in my view since i need the tab flow to be top to bottom

Custom control's Template :

```
   <ControlTemplate>

        <Grid>
           <TextBox x:Name="first"/>
           <TextBox /> 
           <TextBox /> 
        </Grid>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="first" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=first}" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

View :

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefentions>
                <ColumnDefention />
                <ColumnDefention /> 
            </Grid.ColumnDefentions>


            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" TabIndex="0" />
            <local:MyControl Grid.Column="0" TabIndex="1" /> 
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" TabIndex="2" />

            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="3" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="4" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="5" />

        </Grid>
```

when navigating TabIndex 0 in navigated to , then the first textbox in my control and then second and third ,TabIndex 2 **IS NOT** navigated to , it is as if it lost the tab index.

how can i incorporate the navigation inside a custom control's template in the tab flow of the entire view ?

Comment: have you used IsTabStop and AcceptsTab properties ??

Answer (score 0):

Given the same TabIndex as their parent , the items in the parent's visual tree get tabbed in order.

```
<ControlTemplate>

    <Grid>
       <TextBox TabIndex={TempalteBinding TabIndex} />
       <TextBox TabIndex={TempalteBinding TabIndex} /> 
       <TextBox TabIndex={TempalteBinding TabIndex} /> 
    </Grid>
<ControlTemplate>
```

View :

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefentions>
            <ColumnDefention />
            <ColumnDefention /> 
        </Grid.ColumnDefentions>


        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" TabIndex="0" />
        <local:MyControl Grid.Column="0" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="False" /> 
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" TabIndex="2" />

        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="3" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="4" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="5" />

    </Grid>
```